# Determining the :input type in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running an .each() loop on all my form elements. I cannot find a way to determine the input type (whether it's a checkbox, text, select, textarea etc...).

Any ideas?

```
 // When submitting
$("input[name='event_form_submit']").click(function() {
    $("form[name='tepg_form_processor'] :input").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("type"));
       // Determine whether this is a select, input etc?
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What does `$(this).attr("type")` return? That should be fine. You could also simplify it to just `this.type`.

Comment: If you're not getting what you expect, then make sure you're selecting the right stuff - both for your click handler and for the inputs you're looping through. Getting the type values should work if so.

Comment: @James `$(this).attr("type")` won't work for `select`, `textarea` and `button`

Comment: @BrendanBullen - Ah, good point. `this.tagName` will help for that case.

Comment: @JamesAllardice, so if I understand you correctly there isn't a collective function which will return the form "input" type but also break down if it's a input field that it's a checkbox, text etc? I could run multiple conditions to check if it's a input then check the attribute type.

Comment: @MauritzSwanepoel I don't know of any such function. Using type and tagName it's easy to devise one, though.

Comment: Is select input type?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try this (jsfiddle):](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/YSsvp/9/)

```
$("form[name='test'] :input").each(function() {
    alert(this.type);
});
```

Comment: And what about `select` and `textarea`, which don't have a `type` property?

Comment: @DavidThomas that's how jquery implemented it: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("form[name='test'] :input").each(function() {
    if(this.tagName == "INPUT") {
        console.log(this.tagName + ": " + this.type);
    }
    else 
        console.log(this.tagName);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/YSsvp/8/

[Available Input Element Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input)

Comment: I would 1) replace `$(this).prop("tagName")` by the direct access to `this.tagName` 2) [remove any link to w3schools](http://w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$("form[name='test'] :input").each(function() {
    /* gets the type of the element ('checkbox','text','radio', etc
       if there's no 'type' then it retrieves the tagName of the
       element instead 'select','textarea', etc */
    var inputType = this.type || this.tagName.toLowerCase();
    console.log(inputType);
    /* then does uses a switch to do something depending
       on what you want to do */
    switch (inputType) {
        case 'text':
            // do something with text-inputs
            break;
        case 'radio':
            // do something with radio-inputs
            break;
        case 'select':
            // do something with select-elements
            break;
        // ...etc...
        default:
            // do something with other elements, element-types
            break;
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qpY34/).